# String -> ASCII+1 -> Bit string

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, bit-manipulation, ascii

Project:
Add 1 to each character’s numeric ASCII value.
Convert it to a bit string.
Shift the bits of this string one place to the left.
A single-space character in the encrypted string separates the resulting bit strings.

An example of the program input and output is shown below:

Enter a message: Hello world!

0010011 1001101 1011011 1011011 1100001 000011 1110001 1100001 1100111 1011011 1001011 000101

```
# Put your code here
string = input("Enter message: ")

#Convert string from ASCII to Decimal
A_string = [ord(c) for c in string]
print(A_string)

# add 1 to ASCII value 
B_string = A_string
for i in range(len(B_string)):
    B_string[i] = B_string[i] + 1 
print(B_string)


#Decimal to Binary
decimal = B_string
remainder = decimal
Binary_string = decimal

for i in range(len(decimal)):
    remainder[i] = int(decimal[i])
    remainder[i] %= 2
    decimal[i] = decimal[i] // 2
    Binary_string[i] = str(remainder[i] + Binary_string[i])
print(Binary_string)


#Shift Left
length = len(Binary_string)-1
start = 1
shiftLeft = ''
while length !=0:
    shiftLeft = shiftLeft + Binary_string[start] + " "
    length -= 1
    start += 1
shiftLeft += Binary_string[0]
print(shiftLeft)
```

My results:
Enter message: Hello world!

```
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33, 92]
[73, 102, 109, 109, 112, 33, 120, 112, 115, 109, 101, 34, 93]
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

****biggest goal is doing this old school, i.e. NOT using built in functions, and using loops

Answer (score 0):

In the following code example, an input string is converted into a list of ASCII values which are shifted by adding one to them.  This value is then converted back into a string and put into a list called `shiftedChars`. Lastly, these strings are converted into binary.

```
inputString = input("Enter the input string: ")
asciiValues = []
shiftedChars = []
results = []

# loop through each character in the input string
for character in inputString:
    value = ord(character) + 1                           #convert to ascii and shift by 1
    asciiValues.append(value)                            #add to list of ascii values

# loop through each value in the list
for asciiValue in asciiValues:
    shiftedChars.append(chr(asciiValue))                 #convert back to string and store in another list

# loop through each character in the shiftedChar list
for shiftedChar in shiftedChars:
    res = "".join(f"{ord(shiftedChar):08b}")             #convert to binary
    results.append(res)                                  #store result

#print results
for result in results:
    print(result, end=" ")
```

Runtime:

```
Enter the input string: Hello world
```

Output:

```
01001001 01100110 01101101 01101101 01110000 00100001 01111000 01110000 01110011 01101101 01100101
```

Which are the shifted characters `Ifmmp!xpsme` in a binary sequence.

Edit: ----

Some extra explanation for converting into binary from string.
Although it may look extremely confusing syntax, hopefully this will help clear things up.

```
String -> Ascii    - use ord()
Ascii - > Char     - use chr()
Char -> Binary     - convert char using ord() to ascii then format into binary
```

So for this last method of converting to char to binary, we need to first have the ascii numeric value and we will use `.format` for the conversion.

Now looking at `res = "".join(f"{ord(shiftedChar):08b}")` we may be able to break it into smaller parts and find that some code might not be necessary.

Let's look at a smaller sample:

```
print(ord("a"))                         #ord("a")= 97 | using for the shiftedChar
print(format(97, '08b'))                #01100001
emptyString = ""
print(emptyString.join(f"{97:08b}"))    #01100001
```

As you can see, the `format` method takes in a second argument besides the ascii value. This is used to tell how to format for the end result. There are different forms of binary such as ones without leading 0s or sequences that start with `0b`.   Using `.join` on an empty string seems to be mostly for keeping it as a string.  Hopefully this explains what is going on.

Comment: That looks awesome, I'm soooo not there yet as you can see by my coding. I'm also looking for help... in my coding, not a complete program re-written. I have to be able to convert int to binary long form through a loop. Unfortunately:     res = "".join(f"{ord(shiftedChar):08b}")   
is a little further down the road I think =)

Comment: @KrisA I was looking for a more basic way to convert the string to binary, but this seemed to be the easiest for me.  There are some other methods I found but they are even more complicated than this one.  Basically this uses `.join` for a string object and formats what it's joining into binary data. I hope this answers your problem though.

Comment: Old school is definitely more complicated, if you could explain what that line of code is doing then I could use it, but I have to be able to explain it (understand it) to use it

Comment: @KrisA I added some more description to what is happening when converting to binary at the end. Essentially it uses a format method that takes in a character value and an output format as arguments, namely the `shiftedChar` value and  `08b`

Comment: Thank you @Jamin but the coding you did doesn't give the proper answer:
Enter a message: Hello world!

0010011 1001101 1011011 1011011 1100001 000011 1110001 1100001 1100111 1011011 1001011 000101
I see where you added 1 to the ASCII value... I get the converting to string.... still on the res = .... portion (I believe it's taking the characters converting them to binary and adding them back into a string and getting rid of the 0b format.
I'm pretty sure I can code in the shift left, but even shifting characters once to the left won't give me the results I posted in post 1